# Responsive menu yootheme transparent

Tags: css, joomla

I have the issue on this website http://drfernandezconti.com that on responsive smartphone version the menu is transparent on chrome, but not on firefox.

This is also happening on iOs, and I couldn't test it on Android.

It seems some CSS property is not recognized by chrome or iOs, but I don't know wich one is.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the Yootheme support team as it is their template

Comment: Make sure that you have the right css rules for each browsers. Opacity is a good example were you have to set -moz-opacity for Firefox so check that the theme is supported by all-browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could find the problem, just need to add

```
.uk-offcanvas-page { position: relative; }
```

on my custom css. It is a recognized bug by yoo_theme people that will be fixed on the next release.